# How to use nested schema in ORMlite

Tags: c#, sql-server, ormlite, ormlite-servicestack

I am using nested schema in my sqlserver database.
but encounter exception and Invalid object name.

```
[Schema("sam.tst")]
public class Test
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Schema` shouldn't include the table name, you can use:

```
[Schema("sam")]
[Alias("tst")]
public class Test
{
}
```